# Tensor rank as a first order formula

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, tensors, matrix-rank, tensor-rank

I heard in a talk today that the problem of tensor rank over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not even known to be decidable and it is equivalent to the existential theory of over that field. Did not interrupt the speaker since I thought this should be an easy exercise. However I'm finding it quite hard to construct such a formula explicitly.

For matrix rank, I thought I could use the definition that a matrix is of rank $r$ if and only if it can be written as a sum of $r$ rank 1 matrices (which again can be decomposed as $vw^T$ for vectors $v$ and $w$). Now I can set up a system of quadratic equations and quantify over the variables inside. Is this correct?

How would one go about writing such a formula for tensors? The naive way seems to require for a tensor $T:[n]^d \to \mathbb{F}$, something like $n^d$ variables and an equal number of degree $d$ polynomial equations, which seems a little large to me. I heard in the talk that over $\mathbb{R}$, one can then use Tarksi's existential theory of reals (or one of its many efficient implementations) to decide the truth of the formula.

Can someone provide an explicit first order formula for Tensor rank?

Comment: Given a matrix you can clearly compute its rank. I don't know anything about the problem but maybe computing the rank for a $n$-tensor for $n>2$ is the one which is not decidable. Note that your argument only works for $2$-tensors.

Comment: @Levent well, there is a similar decomposition definition for tensors but that linear system will be huge, hence the question

Comment: "Now I can set up a system of linear equations and ask if there is a solution. Is this correct?" The term $vw^T$ is quadratic, not linear.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Oops. you are right! But that does yield a first order formula nevertheless. In the case of higher order tensors, doesn't this formula grow too big? Even the number of variables for a tensor $T: [n]^d \to \mathbb{F}$ is $n^d$.

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field, by Chevalley's theorem, the set of tensors of rank $r$ is constructible, so there exists a finite collection of polynomial equations and inequalities defining this set. However, in virtually all cases, the equations and inequalities are basically completely unknown. Even just the equations, without the inequalities, are unknown. One of the cases where things are known is the $d=2$ case (matrices); there are also the $r=1,2$ cases. There are some other results known but it quickly becomes a collection of special cases. Look up "secant variety equations."